# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer una lista en orden inverso?

Tags: python, lista

Quisiera recorrer una lista en orden inverso en Python. Me sale en C#, Java , etc pero en Python no.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
lista = [100, 200, 500, 2, 36]
n = len(lista)
for i in len(lista):
   print(lista[n])
   n = n-1
```

Peor me sale error en la línea `print(lista[n])`: no me deja pasarle "n" como indice de la lista.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simplemente usa la función [reversed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed), que viene *de serie* con Python:

```
for item in reversed(lista):
    print(item)
```

Para tu lista, devuelve:

```
36
2
500
200
100
```

---

Sobre tu código y por qué no funciona:

```
lista = [100, 200, 500, 2, 36]
n = len(lista)
for i in len(lista):
   print(lista[n])
   n = n-1
```

Antes de nada, si guardas el valor de la longitud de la lista, ¡utiliza esa variable!

Además, estás iterando sobre `len(lista)`, es decir, estás intentando iterar sobre un solo elemento, pues `len(lista)` es un entero. Es como si dijeras `for i in 5`, lo cual hará que iteres una sola vez.

Por tanto, seguramente quieras hacer es recorrer un rango de datos que va de 0 a esa longitud.

Luego, se trata de ir imprimiendo cada vez un elemento de posición -1 respecto el anterior.

Todo junto, quedaría así:

```
lista = [100, 200, 500, 2, 36]
longitud = len(lista)
for i in range(longitud):
      print(lista[longitud-i-1])
```

O, más claramente y como [propone FJSevilla en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146070/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-recorrer-una-lista-en-orden-inverso/146107#comment273953_146107), utilizar un avance negativo para empezar desde el último elemento y así tener un índice más claro:

```
for i in range(longitud-1, -1, -1):
    print(lista[i])
```

Comment: Para iterar sobre la lista en orden inverso sin más,  `reversed` es sin duda la opción más eficiente y la más legible.  Genera un iterador por lo que no crea copia pero también es considerablemente más rápida que `range` + indexado, que solo tiene sentido si modificamos la lista mientras se itera sobre ella. Por cierto como ocurre con `sorted` por ejemplo, las listas también implementan el método `reverse()` (`lista.reverse()`), pero esto invierte la propia lista in-place.

Comment: Fedorqui creo que tienes un pequeño  error tipográfico en el último código:  `lista[n-i-1]`, debería ser  `lista[longitud-i-1]`, otra forma usando `range` sería `for i in range(longitud-1, -1, -1): print(lista[i])`. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla gracias por la sugerencia en tu 2.º comentario, queda mucho más limpio y lo he incorporado a la respuesta. Y sí, había un error tipográfico al haber _jugado_ localmente con el ejemplo y usado _n_ :) ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Además de las soluciones basadas en `reversed()` otro truco que suele verse es utilizar la sintaxis de *slice*, habitualmente usada para extraer un subconjunto de una lista, como en `lista[inicio:fin]`.

El operador slice admite un tercer parámetro, que es el incremento entre índices. Por ejemplo, para sacar elementos cada 2 índices: `lista[inicio:fin:2]`. El incremento puede ser negativo, en cuyo caso `inicio` debe ser mayor que `fin` y los elementos se recorren hacia atrás.
Cuando el incremento es negativo, si se omite `inicio`, se asume el final de la lista y si se omite `fin` se asume el principio.

Juntando todo esto resulta que `lista[::-1]` te devuelve la lista en orden inverso. Así pues:

```
lista = [100, 200, 500, 2, 36]
for dato in lista[::-1]:
   print(dato)
```

Comment: ¡Interesante uso del tercer parámetro de slice, [step o stride](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html)!

Comment: gracias, ha sido de utilidad

Comment: Al usuario que propuso en una edición a la respuesta quitar el bucle y poner `print(lista[::-1])` He rechazado la edición porque el objetivo de la respuesta no era imprimir la lista al revés, sino mostrar cómo iterar por ella hacia atrás, que era lo que pedía la pregunta. El uso de `print` no era más que un ejemplo, se supone que dentro del bucle se puede hacer cualquier otro tipo de procesamiento.

Answer (score 1):

Generalmente en python, puedes usar indices negativos para empezar desde atras.

```
numbers = [10,20,30,40,50]
for i in xrange(len(numbers)):
    print numbers[-i-1]
```

resultado:

```
50
40
30
20
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer un poco de magia con los índices:

```
lista = ['a','b','c','d','e']
print(lista[::-1])
```

Salida:

```
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra posible solución es primero obtener la lista en orden inverso, lo cual es sencillo de hacer mediante la función reversed. Posteriormente, puedes recorrer esa nueva lista normalmente. Cabe destacar que este método es recomendable cuando el tamaño de las lista que manejas es entre pequeño y mediano (unos cuantos miles), de otra forma la creación de una nueva lista puede consumir tiempo y recursos significativos. Por otro lado, usar esta aproximación generalmente es más legible y menos propensa a errores.

Ejemplo, si tienes una lista:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Y haces L2 = reversed(L) obtienes

```
L2 = [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Después puedes hacer la impresión normalmente como:

```
print(*L2, sep='\n')
```

El código anterior funciona en python 3 pero puedes implementar lo mismo en python2 como:

```
for elemento in L2:
    print L2
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacerlo seria:

```
Lista=[1,2,3,4,5]
For i in range(len(lista)-1,0,-1):
      Print(lista[i])
```

salida.

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: gracias, es una forma muy util

Answer (score 0):

Una ayuda a tu código puede ser

```
lista = [100, 200, 500, 2, 36]
n = len(lista)
for i in lista:
   print(lista[n-1],end=' ')
   n = n-1
print()
```

u otra manera es:

```
listainvertida = lista[::-1]
print(listainvertida)
```

una más con el código original, agregando range e intercambiando dos líneas

```
lista = [100, 200, 500, 2, 36]
n = len(lista)
for i in range(len(lista)):
    n = n-1
    print(lista[n],end=' ')
```

36 2 500 200 100

[36, 2, 500, 200, 100]

36 2 500 200 100

Answer (score 0):

Debes de restar uno a n, ya que da el error fuera de rango

```
print(lista[n-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = [100, 200, 500, 2, 36]
n = len(lista)

print("1ra forma")
for i in range(len(lista)):
  n = n - 1
  print(lista[n])

print("2da forma")
for i in lista:
  n = n - 1
  print(lista[n])

print("3ra forma")
for i in lista[::-1]:
  print(i)
```

Comment: Más que una solución deberías de aportar una explicación, de esa manera al OP le puede quedar más claro la manera en como solucionar su problema. Te adjunto [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que te informes más acerca del tema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo soy muy novato en esto de Python, pero para recorrer una lista al reves, es mucho mas sencillo utilizar un bucle while, miren... (tambien con for, pero lo veo mas abstracto de ver)

```
i=len(lista)-1 #se reduce uno porque hay 5 elementos, pero solo 4 posiciones (indices)
while i>=0:
   print('Indice: {} -- Valor: {}'.format(i,lista[i]))
   i-=1 
#con for
for i in range(len(lista)-1,-1,-1):
#se le resta 1 a len por lo mismo de arriba, el segundo -1 porque el cero no lo alcanza y el tercer -1 para decrementar
   print('Indice: {} -- Valor: {}'.format(i,lista[i]))
```